# Saturation Conditions and Quality of CO2 at Exit of Tube

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, adiabatic

I'm stuck on what feels like a simple thermodynamics problem! I was hoping you might be able to shed some light.

I've made a PDF with a detailed write up here: (updated doc with partial answer: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w2bLYPS_Pwgppx-OQHJXWIX_oUZYaENU)

Basically it's about finding the exit properties of saturated CO2 if you flow it from a large reservoir at saturated gas conditions into a small pipe (where upon accelerating it presumably would partially condense into a mixture of liquid and gas at some quality). For some reason I can find solutions up to a point, but then when mass flow rate becomes high enough I can't find a solution which meets my isentropic requirements.

Answer (score 0):

So, after looking at this for a while, I discovered that there are TWO solutions at every increment of mass flow I was looking at. This would pertain to a sub-sonic solution and a supersonic solution, just like you would get using ideal gas relations for compressible flow. This question/answer uses saturated gas tables, but similar physics are at play. When I couldn't find a solution above a certain mass flow this pertained to choked flow, where no matter how low you drop the exit pressure the mass flow rate won't increase. Finding this second valid solution (see the plot in the google PDF doc posted in the original question) was key.